# Tiled Map Editor, Green Lines on the collisions

Tags: tiled

I'm working on a map in Tiled Map Editor. When I run the game my player is standing on the border collisions I made with the Rectangel Object. That's good. But I don't want the green lines to be visible.

https://gyazo.com/ddd9cc7d52c19a679699ee02fe2f74b1

When I try to check off the mark for Visible it doesn't work

https://gyazo.com/f60c046779c5ebef34ac086d834a9a95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to use this 'Visible' property for hiding your collision shapes anyway, since it would be very annoying when trying to adjust them.

Instead, you should look into how you can avoid rendering all your collision shapes, for example by putting them all on a special layer and then not rendering that layer at all. How to go about this depends on which library you're using to load/render the Tiled map.